# First $k$ numbers with given prime factors

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math, prime-factorization

Please help me with the following question. 
There are three prime numbers given $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$. Print the first $k$ numbers with only these prime numbers as factors.

Expected solution complexity: $O(k)$

For example: the three prime numbers are $2, 3, 7$.

First $7$ numbers with these as factors are $2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480291/new-state-of-the-art-in-unlimited-generation-of-hamming-sequence) may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph problem where each node is a number of the form $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}$ From every number there are three edge of the form $(n,p_in)$. You start exploring all the nodes from smallest to largest starting with $s=1$ (you ignore it later if you want) If you keep track of the visited nodes and the neighbors of them, the next node will be in the neighbor list, so you only need to pick the smallest and update the neighbors. Complexity of this approach is $O(k \cdot logk)$ since you need a heap and probably a set to maintain both sets (visited and neighbors).

I've got another algorithm that might improve the complexity of the previous. Let fix some value $T$ and generate all number of interest less than $T$. This can be done in the same way as I mention before. The complexity of this step is $O($Total numbers of interest less than $T)$. Now lets do the following: Start with $T=1$ and while the numbers you have found so far are less than $k$ let $T:=2\cdot T$. After we finish we will have at most $2\cdot k$ numbers. To recover the first $k$ elements you can find the $k^{th}$ element in [linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). So the total complexity of this algorithm will be $O(2 \cdot k + $Times we double $T)$ Since we know that $T \le 2\cdot p_1^{k}$ (Being $p_1$ the smallest among the three of them) $log(T)\le k\cdot log(p_1) + c$ So we will double $T$ at most $k \cdot log(p_1) $, I think a thigther bound might be proved but at least we have an algorithm which is $O(k + klog(p_1))$

Comment: The question asks for an $O(k)$ solution, though.

Comment: is that log base 10?

Comment: @miniparser: The base of a logarithm inside big-O notation does not matter: Different logarithms are related by a constant factor, and big-O explicitly hides such constant factors.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: thanks for the info.  First time ever really being told that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following algorithm will work:

1. Guess an upper bound $u$ for the numbers you're looking for. Your initial guess is some fixed number $\ge 2$. (For simplicity, just say it is $2$).
2. Calculate all multiples of your three primes that are smaller than $u$, but not necessarily in increasing order. This can be done in time linear in the number of multiples you find, by a depth-first search in an (implicit) tree where each multiple appears once -- say, remember for each number you've produced what the *largest* prime factor of it is, and then consider its children to be its product with that and any *larger* primes.
3. If you find fewer than $k$ multiples in step 2, your $u$ was too small. Set $u\leftarrow u^2$ and try again.
4. Use a [linear selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the $k$th smallest among the products you computed in step 2.
5. Output the numbers in the list that are less than or equal to the one you just found. (They won't be in increasing order, but nobody asked for that!)

Why does this run in linear time?

Each time you *square* $u$, roughly eight times as many multiples will be found in the next round. To see this, consider the task of finding the $k$ smallest integer combinations of $\log p_1$, $\log p_2$ and $\log p_3$. This amounts to cutting a tetrahedral corner off the three-dimensional integer lattice $\mathbb N^3$, by a plane whose orientation depends on the ratio between the logarithms. Squaring $u$ corresponds to *doubling* the side lengths in the tetrahedron, so $8$ times as many lattice points will be in the corner we cut off next.

Therefore the *last* round will find at most $8k$ numbers, give or take a few.

And the total effort made in all rounds *other than* the last will be dwarfed by the last round anyway: By familiar properties of geometric series, they will add up to only a seventh of the last round.

---

Actually, you may get away with less work than that, if in each round you keep the results of earlier rounds and just continue the search from the points you discarded as too large in the previous round (which you would also remember). Then you don't have to square $u$ for each round, as long as it does grow fast enough that each discarded point *will* be accepted for the next round (so we can amortize the cost of discarding and reconsidering it). This would correspond to $u\leftarrow p_3u$ instead of $u\leftarrow u^2$, like Marcelo Fornet suggests.

The downside of this is that for *fixed* $k$, $p_1$ and $p_2$, the work we need to spend will then potentially increase when $p_3$ is chosen larger.

To get the best of both worlds we could instead set $u\leftarrow\min(p_3u,u^2)$.

Comment: What about if instead of $u^2$ we use $p_1 u$? I think it will work in $O(k)$.

Comment: @MarceloFornet: I don't think that will grow quicky enough; work will be wasted in step 4 for all the too-small $u$s. In order for the work in the earlier $u$ rounds to be negligible, $\log u$ (and therefore the length of each of the lists from step 2) needs to grow exponentially.

Comment: In step (2) does this not take $n\log(k)$ operations, for a sequence of primes $p_n$?

Comment: I have revised the algorithm to be simple, incorporating some of Marcelo's ideas. Therefore the step 2 that @law-of-fives spoke about is not actually step 2 of the current algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generalization we can assume $p_1 < p_2 < p_3$

OK, the first one is obvious:  $p_1$

For the second one,  pick the smallest one of $p_1^2$ and $p_2$

If that was $p_1^2$, then for the third one pick the smallest one of $p_1^3$, $p_2$

If the second was $p_2$, then for the third one pick the smallest one of $p_1^2$ and $p_3$.

For ones after that, see other Answers!

Comment: What about after that ? Lets say 2,3,7 are there .. The first pick is 2 ( 2,3,7). The second pick is 3 (4,3,7). The third pick is 4 (4,7) How to calculate next?

Comment: @akash  OK, so then we take min(3,2*2,7) = min(3,4,7) = 3.  So since we picked a different prime than the first, the next one is min(2*2,7) = 4.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea using heuristic for this problem when $k$ get larger.

Comment: My question is .. can you develop next 10 numbers using this approach? If yes , please illustrate. It would be very helpful

Comment: @MarceloFornet +1

Comment: @Bram28 if you keep track of only one value how do you guarantee that all numbers will be explored. Notice that the subset of natural numbers we are interested in form a poset and the elements you are building form a chain, if the order is defined by (a is less than b if b is divisible by a)

Comment: @MarceloFornet Yeah, just noticed the error in my ways .. back to the drawing board ... :(